# jquery open div with containing li class="active"

Tags: jquery

I'm using this script for toggling/accordioning divs on my website:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyz/js/jquery.smooth-scroll.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {

    $('#navigation a').smoothScroll({
            easing: 'swing'
        });

    $('.project > .title').click(function(){
        /* Close */
        $(this).parent().siblings().children('.info').slideUp(400);
        $(this).parent().siblings().children('.title').removeClass('flip');
        $(this).parent().siblings('.project').removeClass('open');

        /* Open */
        $(this).toggleClass('flip');
        $(this).parent('.project').toggleClass('open');
        $(this).next('.info').slideToggle(400, function(){
                var project = $(this).parent('.project');
                $.smoothScroll({
                scrollTarget: project,
                easing: 'swing',
                speed: 400
                });
        });
    });

})(jQuery);

</script>
```

for controlling this HTML-markup:

```
<!-- .project -->
<div class="project padding group">
    <div class="title group limiter"><h3>START</h3></div>

    <div class="info group limiter">
        <div class="left">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="aktuell.html" title="AKTUELL" >AKTUELL</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="jobs.html" title="JOBS" >JOBS</a></li>
        <li><a href="presse.html" title="PRESSE" >PRESSE</a></li>
        <li><a href="projekte.html" title="PROJEKTE" >Projekte</a></li>
        <li><a href="archiv.html" title="ARCHIV" >Archiv</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="right">123</div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- .project -->
<div class="project padding group">
    <div class="title group limiter"><h3>COMPANY</h3></div>

    <div class="info group limiter">
        <div class="left">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="1.html" title="1" >1</a></li>
        <li><a href="2.html" title="2" >2</a></li>
        <li><a href="3.html" title="3" >3</a></li>
        <li><a href="4.html" title="4" >4</a></li>
        <li><a href="5.html" title="5" >5</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="right">123</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see that in the first div there is an **li class="active"**. I want to achieve that the **div class "project padding group"** which contains an **li class="active"** is opened on page-load.

Any suggestions on how to make this possible?

Comment: I tried something like this `$('li').hasClass('active', function() {
        $(this).parent().siblings('.project').toggleClass('open');
   });`, but this obviously did not work...

Comment: Do you want to just ' show' the 'li' or add a class to it? Or perform an animation?

Comment: I have made a fiddle with it: [http://jsfiddle.net/CswCf/ ...If you click on **START**, the referred div opens, same as you cick on **COMPANY**. I want to have the div opened that contains an **li** with **active** like in the START-div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a cleaner approach?

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/72bBJ/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#navigation a').smoothScroll({
    easing: 'swing'
});

$('.title').click(function() {
    $('.info').slideUp(400);
    $(this).parent('div').find('.info').slideDown(400);
});

$('li.active').closest('.info').slideDown(400);

});
```

Comment: thanks for your post, but unfortuneately this didn't work for me...if I add your code nothing happens anymore.

Comment: @Em  I misunderstood your question at first, this should work :)

Comment: I'm on my phone viewing this , can't test it :/

Comment: thx again for your EDIT! But this didn't work for me either (I've recognized the typing error with the second has**s**Class and corrected it, but it still doesn't work)

Comment: @EMEm If you want the user to be able to close the open section by clicking on the title, use this script http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/72bBJ/1/

Comment: thx again VIDesignz, but the user shouldn't be able to close the div containing the active-li...but you made my day!

Comment: the way it works in your first fiddle/with the posted code  is fine for me! If I click on the Title-link the div gets closed and opened again. But unfortunately I can't accept your answer because I don't have enough reputation :(

Comment: @EMEm Oh, it's cool! I'll upvote your question, give you a boost!

Comment: ah, sorry...I can accept it but not vote it up...I made this now...thx again!

Answer (score 0):

use the following selector:

```
$( 'li.active' ).closest( 'div.project.padding.group' )
```

Comment: thx Giovanni for your post, too! I tried this with a slight correction `$( 'li.active' ).closest( 'div.project.padding.group' ).toggleClass('open');`, but both didn't work for me. But there is something happening, when adding this code, but not the way I want it (the top-border grows on page-reload, but the div doesn't get full opened)

Comment: You should check for syntax errors within your Javascript. Try pasting everything on http://www.jshint.com/ or other similar tool. Also, try these suggestions on the Google Chrome javascript console (right button on the page/"Inspect Element"/go to last tab: "Console").

Comment: I see that too, the js code is valid, though I think it could be cleaned up a bit...

Comment: i've checked the code via jshint.com, which shows me two errors.one of them i could resovle, but the 2nd one is about the `})(jQuery);` at the end. If I remove `(jQuery)` the code doesn't work at all...I tried the other solution with Google Chrome Javascript console, but there I don't get any output.

Comment: don't take JSHint for face value, it's there just to point you to possible catastrophic mistakes. Also, did you tried just `$( 'li.active' ).closest( 'div.project.padding.group' )` at the Chrome Console? It should -- if there is this element at the page somewhere -- show the selected element. After all, `$( 'li.active' ).closest( 'div.project.padding.group' )` is a selector. Try different selectors. Your problem seems simple, but I can't see it from here. You should tweak it using the Chrome Console and you'd probably solve and also learn a lot about jQuery and Javascript.

Comment: One other thing: `$` is an wrapper for `jQuery`, but there's some complication on the use of one or other I don't know much about (in Wordpress, for example, you can't use `$` for default, just `jQuery`). So, if you're using `$` but your code uses `jQuery` (maybe is Wordpress code), try replacing `$` for `jQuery` in your code too (damn confusing comment).